# How can I find ceiling joists underneath this wood paneling?

Tags: framing, studs, beam

Out on our front porch we'd like to hang a swing, but I can't figure out where any of the joists are underneath the wood paneling.

I can't find any nails or screws of any sort and my stud finder isn't working on this (presumably because the paneling is wood as well).

Any ideas how I'd go about finding the beams to put some eye hooks?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would check below the eve where those come out there is usually a 2×  that the sheeting is nailed or screwed to. If this is lap a magnetic stud finder will locate the fasteners(they are just a small magnet on a pivot when over the fastener the magnet points to it) .

Comment: It is possible that nails or screws were caulked over and then painted. This would be more difficult to find, but could still be found with close inspection

Comment: A good quality stud finder will do the job, about $20.00.  Read the instructions carefully and follow.  This could take some time. Be willing to give your due diligence.

Comment: That is a nice looking porch -- siding, window trim, and ceiling.  It is quite possible that the ceiling joists are not designed for the point loads that a hanging porch swing would apply.

Comment: I would recommend a professional grade stud finder.  Bosh makes a nice one Model # GMS120.  It can find studs through up to 4 inches, it finds electrical runs.  It is ~$80 or so.  If you have "layered" surfaces.  This is the tool for you!  I lived in an 1854 post & beam house, with Red Oak and Black Walnut framing. (it is a long story) I had layers that a 4" drywall screw couldn't find anything solid.  This thing "beamed" into the walls to find the beams. :)  Good Luck!

Comment: Those boards are running in the same direction I would have expected the ceiling joists to run. That leads me to suspect that there are some runners installed on the joists perpendicular to them. If you find those you shouldn't use them to carry any load.

Answer (score 1):

That looks similar to T-111 siding that should be nailed to the joists every 16 or 24 inches. The key would be to find the seams where the pieces join. The other seams are just for looks and won't have any joists under them.

Using a thin piece plywood or shim to bang on, you can hold that against the ceiling and bang with a hammer to hear the hollow and solid spots without damaging your ceiling.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have a chance of finding the studs if you borrow a thermal camera, and it's a hot day with enough temperature difference.

But quite frankly can you find a way into that structure from above?  Seeing it for real is the ground truth.